# protect the excel from being opened in php

Tags: php, laravel, zip

How to protect excel file from being opened in php. i have created password protected zip file using

```
exec(zip -p file.zip /path);
```

but problem i faced here is when i tried to extract password protected zip in windows. i works fine in linux OS but not in windows.

Can anybody suggest me how to protect excel file with password in php either with zip method or directly password on excel file using PHP Code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the setEncryption method?

```
$dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("pass", "pass");
```

Comment: I made you an example, I do not know how do you refer to dompdf inside your code. The setEncryption is what you need to implement in order to password protect your generated file.

Comment: this one is working, however im getting a blank pdf page when the <style> tag is included, do you know how to fix it? i need help, Thank You @SimoneCabrino

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Simone is very close.

Here is a working example with Laravel 5.4 and the [Laravel DOMPDF wrapper by barryvdh](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf):

```
 $content = 'some html';
 $dompdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
 $dompdf->loadHTML($content)->setPaper('a4');
 $dompdf->getDomPDF()->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("pass", 'your_password');
```

If you are not using the barryvdh package, simply inspect your the dompdf library until you find the methods which retrieve the `Canvas` class and then the `CPDF`class, which contains the `setEncryption` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this one is working, however im getting a blank page when the <style> tag is included, do you know how to fix it? i need help, Thank You @yani

Comment: @apelidoko I'm not sure and will be hard to say without looking at the code. One thing I can say is that DomPDF is very unforgiving when it comes to CSS errors (but it does support css) and, if I remember correctly, some tags may cause issues. So make sure you lint your CSS and if that doesn't work try to remove line by line until you find the problematic line.

Comment: hi @Yani I saw the problem,it was an invalid element in my css, Thank You, didnt know it was too sensitive.

Comment: I have a new problem, the setEncryption doesnt work on paper size letter, but it works on a4, do you know how to fix this problem? thank you so much,

Comment: @apelidoko Glad it helped. I'm afraid you're on your own with that one. You can inspect the code until you figure out the problem, that's how I found the original solution to this post.